# Storing value in variable adds one character of length

Tags: bash, perl

I am generating 20 digits long id using perl inside bash script. When I run only the perl, it gives me 20 digits long string. If I save it to variable and then echo it, it's 21 digits long. 
Can someone please explain this to me?
The code:

```sh
perl -e 'my @chars = ("0".."9",);my $string;$string .= $chars[rand @chars] for 0..19; print $string;'
```

```sh
ID=$(perl -e 'my @chars = ("0".."9",);my $string;$string .= $chars[rand @chars] for 0..19; print $string;' )
echo $ID
```

Comment: Please provide sample outputs and your length-calculation mechanism by [edit]ing your Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t show how you’re computing length, but `echo` prints arguments with a trailing newline.

In `sh` and descendants, you can use `printf '%s' "$ID"` to print without a trailing newline.

Pipe your `echo` and my `printf` through `xxd` to observe the difference.

### Examples

Setup:

```
# ID="$(perl -e 'my @chars=("0".."9");my $string;$string.=$chars[rand @chars] for 0..19;print $string')"
```

#### `printf`

```
# printf '"%s" ' "$ID" "no trailing whitespace"
"37308262201981702169" "no trailing whitespace" # printf '%s' "$ID" | wc -c
      20
# printf '%s' "$ID" | xxd
00000000: 3337 3330 3832 3632 3230 3139 3831 3730  3730826220198170
00000010: 3231 3639                                2169
```

This is an output of 20 characters exactly. You can even see how the prompt doesn't appear on the next line in the printf versions.

#### `echo`

```
# echo "$ID"
37308262201981702169
# echo "$ID" | wc -c
      21
# echo "$ID" | xxd
00000000: 3337 3330 3832 3632 3230 3139 3831 3730  3730826220198170
00000010: 3231 3639 0a                             2169.
```

This is an output of 21 characters exactly. The last character is `0x0a` is a newline.

Comment: For completeness, `echo` also has an `-n` flag that suppresses the trailing newline.

Comment: I count the length piping it to wc
` | wc -c `
but my main problem is that the second one has one more digit (readable digin from 0 to 9) when later saved i nthe file

Comment: @ales_t which is highly non-portable. Hell, `echo` is highly non-portable (ever tried to `echo` the literal string `-n`? There’s practically no mechanism to disable echo’s options, but POSIX says echo prints exactly its arguments with a trailing newline. I have yet to find a POSIX echo beyond `printf '%s\n' -- "$@"`). I recommend against it almost always.

Comment: `⇒  printf '%s' $X | xxd`
`00000000: 3439 3537 3937 3737 3636 3439 3938 3138  4957977766499818`
`00000010: 3338 3336                                3836`
`⇒  echo $X | xxd`
`00000000: 3439 3537 3937 3737 3636 3439 3938 3138  4957977766499818`
`00000010: 3338 3336 0a                             3836.`

Comment: @Hahihula `wc` like that probably counts the newline (`0a` in xxd’s output). Do you see the difference now?

Comment: @ales_t And I was still wrong. A closer version is `echo () { printf '%s' "$@"; printf '\n';}` but that doesn't preserve the separation of arguments. `echo` is hard to get POSIX. `printf` is not.